# Software raid5 recovery

Tags: raid

I'm very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so please forgive my noobness.

I'm running an Ubuntu server, where the OS is installed on a SSD drive. In addition, I have 4 other drives in a software raid5. One of these drives failed.

I recently upgraded to 12.10, and after doing so, the system refuses to boot, and gets stuck after choosing what installation to boot.

I have replaced the failed drive with a new one, and now I'm trying to recover the system by booting from a USB installation drive, but I'm really stuck on what to do.

Some questions.
1. How can identify my SSD drive from the other drives, in case I will try a fresh install
2. How can I rescue my failed raid?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `mdadm` command to add the new drive to the array and then wait for it to resync.  See the man page for details.

Also check out the RAID wiki: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid

Answer (score 0):

1) run: fdisk -l

It will list all the drives in your system. An easy way to find which one is you SSD, is looking for the size of it. They should be listed like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 1006 MB, 1006108672 bytes
```

2) Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm